# Is there a Go profiler?

Tags: profiling, go

I played around with Go a bit shortly after it came out. There wasn't a profiler then; is there one now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use pprof package, and [Google perftools](http://code.google.com/p/google-perftools/).

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `gccgo` compiler instead of the `6g` compiler, you'd probably be able to use the normal GNU tools, i.e. `gprof`.

I haven't actually *done* it with `gprof`, but I at least know that it works for `gdb`.